# How do I return the value of a Promise from a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I know you can access a Promise’s value inside the `.then` method like the following code:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const mergeValues = require('./helper').mergeValues;


fs.readFileAsync('./index.html', {encoding: "utf8"})
    .then((data) => {
        return mergeValues(values, data); //async function that returns a promise
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

In the above example, I’m reading from a file, merging the data with some values, and then logging the data to the console.

But how about returning the value from a function, as you normally would in a synchronous function? If I follow [this comment on synchronous inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain/#answer-28252015), I think the code should look like this:

```
function getView(template, values) {
    let file = fs.readFileAsync('./' + template, {encoding: "utf8"});
    let modifiedFile = file.then((data) => {
            return mergeValues(values, data);
        });
    return modifiedFile.then((data) => {
        return modifiedFile.value();
    });
}
console.log(getView('index.html', null));
```

But for some reason, it’s not working. All I’m getting in the console is the Promise object itself, not the value. And when I add the `.isFulfilled` method on `modifiedFile`, it outputs to `true`. So I’m not sure what I’m doing incorrectly.

Comment: You can never ever return a value from async. Ever. Canonical answer: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Once you commit to an async call everything past that depends on any results of that operation is by definition async as well. That is, if you use a Promise in your function and you need to get something back from it, return a promise. You can't wait around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises don't work that way. They are *asynchronous* by nature, so you can't interact with them in the same way you do with synchronous code.

That means you *have to* use the `then` method to get at the value:

```
function getView(template, values) {
    let file = fs.readFileAsync('./' + template, {encoding: "utf8"});
    let modifiedFile = file.then((data) => {
            return mergeValues(values, data);
        });
    return modifiedFile.then((data) => {
        return modifiedFile.value();
    });
}
// This won't work
// console.log(getView('index.html', null)); 

// instead:
getView('index.html', null).then(function (view) {
    console.log(view);
});
```

> So I’m not sure what I’m doing incorrectly.

You're not doing anything incorrectly, actually. You just can't use promises like a normal return value from a function. Period.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!